# How can i get the id of new created card on trello?

Tags: php, api, trello

I'm using this api for trello (https://github.com/cdaguerre/php-trello-api) and i'm simply trying to get the id of the new created card.

```
$card = $manager->getCard();
$card
    ->setDueDate($due)
    ->setName('Order ' . $x[0]['job_no'] . ' [' . $x[0]['vendorAdd']. ']')
    ->setDescription($description)
    ->setPosition('top')
    ->save();
```

If i do:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($card);
echo "<pre>;
```

I can see in the array the id but how can i have access to it ?

```
[data:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5911248b7235447f23768e69
            [badges] => Array
                (
                    [votes] => 0
                    [viewingMemberVoted] => 
                    [subscribed] => 
                    [fogbugz] => 
                    [checkItems] => 0
                    [checkItemsChecked] => 0
                    [comments] => 0
                    [attachments] => 0
                    [description] => 1
                    [due] => 2017-05-10T14:00:00.000Z
                    [dueComplete] => 
                )

            [checkItemStates] => Array
                (
                )

            [closed] => 
            [dueComplete] => 
            [dateLastActivity] => 2017-05-09T02:08:11.421Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question I know, but an answer would have saved me a bit of time...

```
$card = $manager->getCard();

$card
  ->setDueDate($due)
  ->setName('Order ' . $x[0]['job_no'] . ' [' . $x[0]['vendorAdd']. ']')
  ->setDescription($description)
  ->setPosition('top')
  ->save();

$cardId = $card->getId();

echo $cardId;
```